# WordPress Edit Page editor unresponsive - jQuery Error?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, editor, admin

When I go to edit my page I cannot open screen options or switch between visual and Text mode in the editor.

I've tried adding

```
define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false);
define('SCRIPT_DEBUG', true);
```

to wp config but it hasn't helped

My jQuery load script is this

```
function loadJquery()
{
    if ($hook != 'post-new.php' || $hook != 'post.php' ) {
        wp_register_script('siteJs',get_template_directory_uri() . 
'/js/site.js',array('jquery'),'1.4.1');
        wp_enqueue_script('siteJs'); // Enqueue it!
    }
}
```

I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Referring to this:

```
(function() {
    var burger = document.querySelector('.navbar-burger');
    var menu = document.querySelector('.navbar-menu');
    burger.addEventListener('click', function() {
    burger.classList.toggle('is-active');
    menu.classList.toggle('is-active');
});
```

And as the page sits there it also brings up this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasClass' of undefined
>   at HTMLDocument. (wp-auth-check.js:101)

Comment: Does site.js need to load in WP admin? If not, try enqueueing the script with `add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'loadJquery' );` instead of wherever loadJquery is currently loading. (You'd need to remove the if statement checking the $hook value for this...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using

```
wp_print_scripts
```

to load jQuery, when as dafoxuk said I should be using

```
wp_enqueue_scripts()
```

Answer (score 1):

The error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null` is indicating that `burger` is undefined. While it may be worth reviewing whether site.js should be running on the WP Admin (where `.navbar-burger` doesn't even exist), the direct fix is to check whether `burger` is found before adding the event listener.

This would look like:

```
(function() {
var burger = document.querySelector('.navbar-burger');
var menu = document.querySelector('.navbar-menu');
if (burger != null && menu !=  null){
     burger.addEventListener('click', function() {
     burger.classList.toggle('is-active');
     menu.classList.toggle('is-active');
  });
}
})();
```

Comment: It was simply me loading Jquery with wp_print_scripts instead of enqueue
Thanks!